# Keyboard doesn't detect upon wake. Need to disconnect and reconnect it every time

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, suspend, acer

I have a Acer Switch Alpha 12 laptop where the screen is detachable from the keyboard.

When the computer wakes up, even if the keyboard is connected it is not usable. I need to disconnect and reconnect it, then it works.

I am hoping there's a script I can make run every time the computer wakes which scans for the keyboard and connects it. Similar to how with the wifi I can run `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Comment: I have the same device with the same problem.  Did you ever figure out why this was happening?  Also, kind of irrelevant question, did you ever get rotation working on linux? Also did you ever figure out how to uefi boot using the tablet?  Those are two things that I could never figure out about this damned device.

Comment: @CarsenDanielYates With deep regret I ended up deleting my Linux partition for the space and now I use Bash on Windows when I need to. And no, I didn't get the rotation working on Linux. I don't know how to do UEFI boot either. Actually, somehow I got into a wierd setup where if I turn on Legacy boot (no EFI) I could boot Linux, and I got to the Windows boot by turning on UEFI and disabling secure boot. Even now that I've deleted Linux I still have to disable secure boot to use windows.